# Listing all files in a Google Cloud Storage bucket and its pricing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

When using the [bucket.getFilesStream](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.3.x/Bucket#getFilesStream), which auto-paginates through the files in a bucket, is each page's worth of data request considered single Class A operations? Or is the entire stream using pagination considered a single Class A operation?

If it's multiple operations, is there a cheaper way to get a list of all files in a bucket, assuming there are millions of files?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official Cloud Storage JSON API reference](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/#Objects) the method for listing the bucket objects is `storage.objects.list`. It retrieves a list of objects matching the specified criteria. This is the method used in the client libraries to retrieve list of object in the bucket. As long as this is the only method to achieve this, there isn't any workaround to list the buckets objects in a cheaper way.

As you can see in the [Google Cloud Storage pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class) a call to this method is considered as a Class A operation. The number of calls would depend on how the node.js uses the JSON API.